# How to get custom attribute value in after product collection load in Observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, collection, catalog, magento2.4.2-p1

I want to get multiple select type custom attribute values in product collection observer,
I have tried with some events **catalog_block_product_list_collection, catalog_product_collection_apply_limitations_after or catalog_product_collection_load_after**

Observer look like as below:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {    
            $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/plugin_for_product_collection.log');
            $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
 
            $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getData('collection');
            foreach ($collection as $item) {
                $logger->info('item: ', [$item->getName()]);
                $logger->info('item->getCustomerIds(): ', [$item->getCustomerIds()]);
                $logger->info('item->getCustomAttribute: ', [$item->getCustomAttribute('customer_ids')]);
                $logger->info('item->getCustomerIds: ', [$item->getData('customer_ids')]);
                $logger->info('item->getAllAttributeValues(customer_ids): ', [$item->getAllAttributeValues('customer_ids')]);
            }

            return $this;
        }
```

Result are showing as bellow:

```
– 2022-02-04T21:44:28+00:00 INFO (6): item:  ["Product Name showing perfect"]
– 2022-02-04T21:44:28+00:00 INFO (6): item->getCustomerGroup():  [null]
– 2022-02-04T21:44:28+00:00 INFO (6): item->getCustomAttribute:  [null]
– 2022-02-04T21:44:28+00:00 INFO (6): item->getCustomerGroup:  [null]
– 2022-02-04T21:44:28+00:00 INFO (6): item->getAllAttributeValues(customer_group):  [null]
```

Yet when I use **$item->getData()** showing product data but not showing custom attribute value. Am I missing something else? or am I using the wrong event to list the products? Any help would be really appreciated.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Why do you want to use event observer? Can you explain on which page you want your custom attributes values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This Observer : **catalog_product_collection_load_after**

and Try to select the attribute before foreach in the collection.

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/plugin_for_product_collection.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);

        $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getData('collection');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect(['custom_attribute_code_1','custom_attribute_code_2']);
        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $logger->info('item: ', [$item->getName()]);
            $logger->info('item->getCustomerIds(): ', [$item->getCustomerIds()]);
            $logger->info('item->getCustomAttribute: ', [$item->getCustomAttribute('customer_ids')]);
            $logger->info('item->getCustomerIds: ', [$item->getData('customer_ids')]);
            $logger->info('item->getAllAttributeValues(customer_ids): ', [$item->getAllAttributeValues('customer_ids')]);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Great, I have tried to select the attribute before foreach working fine. Thank you!